# How can I select a max date from a selection of dates less than another table's max?

Tags: sql, subquery, max, aggregate, ingres

**Question:**

How can I select the `max(d1_10.dstartdate)` (latest unit transfer date) for every `xpid` (patient ID) from a selection of dates in `d1_10` that are less than each `xpid`'s `max(d8.start_date)` (latest session date)?

**Info:**

Tables:

- `d0` Patient List Table, contains 1 row per `xpid` (patient)

  - `d0.xpid` Unique Patient ID
- `d8` Session Table, contains 1 row per session per `xpid`

  - `d8.xpid` Patient ID
  - `d8.start_date` Session Start Date
- `d1_10` Unit Transfer Table, contains 1 row per transfer per `xpid`

  - `d1_10.dstartdate` Transfer Date

**Problem:**

Currently I have a query that lists `xpid`, `max(d8.start_date)`, and `max(d1_10.startdate)`. But, `max(d1_10.startdate)` isn't necessarily less than `max(d8.start_date)`

The goal is to have a list of all patients, their latest session date, and their latest transfer date *that was still prior to their session date*. Currently transfer date is independent of session date.

I have tried nesting the join queries, but haven't been able to figure out the scope of calling the variables.

**Progress:**

This is the closest running code I have:

```
select distinct
    d0.xpid,
    sessions.max_date,
    units.max_unit
from d0
    left join
        (
            select xpid, max(start_date) as max_date
            from d8
            group by xpid
        ) as sessions on sessions.xpid = d0.xpid
    left join
        (
            select xpid, max(d1_10.dstartdate) as max_unit
            from d1_10
            group by xpid
        ) as units on units.xpid = d0.xpid
```

Snippet from Output:

[image: Output Sample]

Note the `null` values, these are good, we want these. We want one row of output for every patient in `d0` regardless of their rows in `d8` or `d1_10`.

Thanks in advance, please let me know if I can provide more clarity.

**Additional Info:**

- Tried adding `and units.max_unit <= sessions.max_date` as suggested by Sebastian. It's close, but instead of restricting by `max_unit <= max_date`, we need that all `d1_10.dstartdate <= sessions.max_date` before taking the max. We want it to restrict the pool it picks `units.max_unit` from before taking the maximum.
- @Sebastian, Suppose `xpid = 2500` has 3 rows in `d1_10` with `d1_10.dstartdate in ('01-jan-2017', '01-feb-2017', '01-mar-2017')` and `max(d8.start_date) = '10-feb-2017'`.

  With your suggestion, `max_unit is null`, because the `max(d1_10.dstartdate) = '01-mar-2017'`, but `'01-mar-2017 > '10-feb-2017'`.

  We need to restrict `d1_10.dstartdate <= max(d8.start_date)` before taking the maximum. The desired value should be `max_unit = '01-feb-2017'` because this is the maximum transfer date for this patient that is less than this patient's maximum session date. Let me know if I can clear it up better.

Comment: Please add sample data set

Comment: Adding `AND d1_10.max_unit < sessions.max_date` to the on clause of the second left join should be enough

Comment: @realspirituals preferred method of doing so? Excel sheets in a .rar?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "we need that all 'd1_10.dstartdate <= sessions.max_date'". If you mean that every d1_10.dstartdate of one patient should be less or equal d8.start_date, you already got it, because you are selecting the max date of each patient, so the other dates are less or equal to that date.

Comment: @SebastianS. We need to restrict the set `max(d1_10.dstartdate)` to be chosen from the dates `<= sessions.max_date`, not restrict the set of maximums generated by `max(d1_10.dstartdate)`. I'll add an example to help illustrate it

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
AND d1_10.max_unit < sessions.max_date
```

to the on clause of the second left join is enough.

After your edit, please try that one:

```
SELECT  d0.xpid,
        d8.[start_date],
        d1_10.dstartdate
FROM d0
LEFT JOIN d8
    ON d0.xpid = d8.xpid
LEFT JOIN d1_10
    ON d1_10.xpid = d8.xpid
    AND d1_10.dstartdate = (
                                SELECT MAX(u1.dstartdate)
                                FROM d1_10 as u1
                                WHERE d8.xpid = u1.xpid 
                                AND u1.dstartdate <= d8.start_date
                                GROUP BY u1.xpid
                            )
```

Comment: Turns out this didn't do it. Not yet anyway, hoping you can help me get there

Comment: Adding info add the bottom of the question